# Differences between IntelliJ IDEA 13 and Android Studio

Tags: java, android

For a long time Android Studio provided better ide integration compared to IntelliJ IDEA.

To my knowledge version 13 of the IntelliJ IDE does include all the features that previous versions were lacking.

My question is: Are there still any exclusive features of Android Studio so that it makes sense to have a separate installation besides IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Many of the questions regarding the differences between the two [have been covered in a blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/).

The gist of it is that the Android plugin for IntelliJ and Android Studio itself come from the same codebase. New features introduced in Android Studio will be available in IntelliJ as well, if not immediately then soon enough.

Android Studio offers an Android specific development environment with some of the common setup tasks (including Gradle) more streamlined.

IntelliJ is targeted towards developers who do both Android as well as regular Java development.  So if you use IDEA for more than just Android development, you are better off sticking with it.

Comment: I have to agree with this answer. I spent 10 HOURS yesterday to get a very basic non-android java project working in Android Studio and while it imported just fine, It was giving me errors left and right, and the debugger wasn't working properly.

Comment: @Donato Reverse is true as well. To be honest all of this talk regarding IntelliJ having native android support is a lie.

With Android Studio - you install it and it works.
With IntelliJ (Ver. 15.02 Ultimate) - you first install Android SDK(bundled with android studio by default) then you have 3 pop up windows asking you to install one thing or another, then you end up to similar layout as Android Studio, you drag and drop UI text label elements to your phone image as test "hello" project and it hangs infinitely. Pathetic experience.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [Jetbrains' blog:](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/)

The EAP of IntelliJ IDEA 13, which includes all of the Android Studio features except for the redesigned new project wizard and the App Engine cloud endpoints integration is available now.

BTW new features of Android Studio won't be available for users of IntelliJ IDEA v12. The new features (especially the Gradle support) depend on the major changes that were done in the version 13 platform, and there is no plans to backport them.

Comment: @Shah> Yes, please read [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/)webpage. I just marked some most important parts in my answer.

Comment: You need to specify that new features for AS won't be available for IDEA version 12 **only** - in the second part of your answer it sounds like you mean they won't be available at all. The gist (as @Shah pointed out) is that AS and IDEA **will have the same features**, it might just take a bit longer for them to become available in IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experiences and [IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/)

- First of all, both use the same base code. So there's no actual
  difference in that part.

> Android Studio and the Android plugin for IntelliJ IDEA are built from
>   the same code, and all of the changes in Android Studio are, and will
>   continue to be, available in IntelliJ IDEA releases.

- Android studio is **only** developed to produce android applications.

> Android Studio is focused specifically on Android development and
>   provides streamlined environment and project setup

But Intellij IDEA has features to produce other stuffs like JAVA programs.

- You can't really trust Android studio (and it's almost 2016) to be
  completely stable as it still has some bugs which are unlikely in
  Intellij Idea.
- If you rely on features that are only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (such as additional version control plugins), you won't be able to use Android Studio?

> these additional features will not be available in Android Studio. You
>   should continue using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

- The only advantage I've seen in Android studio over Intellij IDEA is automatically adding support for `appcompat` to the project and not having to go through [the steps to add it to the project](https://www.in-nomine.org/2012/02/26/adding-android-support-v4-to-your-android-application-in-intellij-idea/)

*So I would personally use Intellij IDEA and wait for Google to release a more stable Android studio version*